# How to print comments in a given program?

Tags: c

I want to print the comment to a given program to be printed in console?

Is there any function and any own logic to get print the comment in a program?

e.g.

```
 int main()
 {
   /* this is a comment */
 }
```

the above program has only one comment i want to print this comment to console by a certain logic or any function ,if there is in C?

Comment: ya the use of printf will be neccessary but how to do it?

Comment: Ya i tried to do this with the help of file handling in C.but nothing went as i wanted to do.

Comment: on runetime or on compile time? should "this is a comment" be printed to the console, while the programm executes? or do you like to see all the comments for inspection purpose?

Comment: @PeterMiehle:  at runtime the comment should be as the output of the program

Comment: If the sole purpose of the program is to output its "comments", then "comment" is the wrong term to be using. "Logging", "printing" and "outputting" all seem more appropriate terms. Are you sure you have understood the intention of the homework assignment?

Comment: @Als using pritnf() will take forever for long programs

Answer (score 8):

You need to write a program that reads c source files, and identifies and prints comments within these files.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void read_until_char (FILE *f, char c) {
   // read file until c is found 
}

void read_until_char_into (FILE *f, char c, char *buf) {
   // read file until c is found
   // also write each char read into buffer 
}

void print_comments(const char *filename) {
  FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
  char buffer[2048];
  int c;
  if (f) {
    while (!feof(f)) {
      read_until_char(f, '/');
      c = fgetc(f);
      if (c == '*') {
        while (!feof(f)) { 
          read_until_char_into(f, '*', buffer);
          if ((c=fgetc(f)) == '/') { 
            // print buffer 
            break;
          } else if (c == '*') { 
            // consider what to do if c is *
          }
        }
      } else if (c == '/') {
         read_until_char_into(f, '\n', buffer);
         // print buffer
      }
    }
    fclose(f);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A compiled C program without access to its own source code will not be able to print the comments. The comments are removed by the C preprocessor, and never even seen by the compiler. In other words, the comment text is not available once the program is executable.

This is why your approach is going to have to be to somehow process the source code directly, you can't do this at runtime for the program itself.

Comment: we can do it >..as we have a __FILE__ macro defined in C.that provides us the content of file in the same C file.

Comment: @krishnaChandra No, that is not what the `__FILE__` macro expands to. It gives you the name of the current translation unit, i.e. the filename. Not the entire source code.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://amit.chakradeo.net/files/xscc.awk.txt) is an awk script that can extract comments out of your sourcecode file.

Comment: On one hand, the code presently behind that link is the most comprehensive answer yet available. On the other hand, answers that become useless if the links they contain break are not considered complete and self-contained enough to be acceptable here. Since the license only requires retaining credit (and appears CC-BY-SA compatible) and the source itself is short, maybe copy the copyright notice and the code into the answer, and link to the original file for more extended documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can invert your questions.  Why not use a string (which you can print) as a comment?  The point of comments is that

- They can hold pretty free-form text.
- Humans can read it when looking at the source code.

String literals have both of these characteristics.

Thus

```
void a_function()
{
    docstring = "This string is a comment. Blah blah.";
    printf("DOC %s", docstring);
}
```

(Python has a [very similar convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), and this is where I get the name "docstring").

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [How can I delete all /* */ comments from a C source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714530/how-can-i-delete-all-comments-from-a-c-source-file) and then make a diff between the generated file and the original file.

Answer (score 0):

It's a sort of program called a `Quine`

C example:

```
main(){char *c="main(){char *c=%c%s%c;printf(c,34,c,34);}";printf(c,3
4,c,34);}
```

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29)

Comment: Also, half a multiquine won't really work. Especially without any output code. I've replaced it with a small C quine from [the quine page](http://www.nyx.net/~gthompso/quine.htm). You can roll it back if  you disagree with the edit

Answer (score 0):

I'm very confused about this question, if you want to print every comment why not just use a string instead of a comment? Or both? Why do you need to print the comments of your program? Just wondering because I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, and perhaps there is a better way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Does `printf("/*foo*/");` not work or something? Or are you trying to make this automatic?

If it's the latter then you will need to have your program parse your source file and search for comments (unless there is some other easier magical way).

I suggest you just read the C file char by char until you encounter a `/*` and start populating an array with each char until the next occurrence of `*/`.

If for whatever reason the problem you are having is the former, and you can't for some reason print a comment with `printf` here's a function I wrote to make a comment string (very pointless since I'm 99% sure you can just use `printf("/*foo*/")` .

```
int printcomment(const char *comment)
{
    char *commentln, open[] = "/*", close[] = "*/";
    if(!(commentln = malloc(strlen(comment) + 5))) return 0;
    strcat(commentln, open);
    strcat(commentln, comment);
    strcat(commentln, close);
    printf("%s", commentln);
    free(commentln);
    return 1;
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java version which extracts single line and multiline comments (not tested exhaustively).

```
public void showComments(String fileName) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    FileReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new FileReader(fileName);

        int ch = -1;
        boolean singleLineComment = false;
        boolean multiLineComment = false;
        char prev = (char)ch;
        while ((ch = br.read()) != -1) {
            if (ch == '/' && prev == ch && !singleLineComment) {
                singleLineComment = true;
            } else if (ch == '*' && prev == '/' && !multiLineComment) {
                multiLineComment = true;
            } else if (ch == '\n' && singleLineComment) {
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                singleLineComment = false;
                sb = new StringBuffer();
            } else if (ch == '/' && prev == '*' && multiLineComment) {
                System.out.println(sb.toString());
                multiLineComment = false;
                sb = new StringBuffer();
            } else if (multiLineComment || singleLineComment) {
                sb.append((char)ch);
            }
            prev = (char)ch;
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can handle single line comment.

```
  while((scanf("%c",&s[i]))!=EOF)
        {
            b[i]=s[i];
           if(s[i]=='\n')
            {
                for(j=k; j<=i; j++)
                {
                    if(s[j]=='/')
                    {
                        if(s[j+1]=='/')
                        {
                            temp=1;

                        }
                        else if(s[j+1]=='*')
                        {
                            for(j=j+2; j<=i; j++)
                            {
                                if(s[j]=='*')
                                {
                                    if(s[j+1]=='/')
                                    {
                                        temp=1;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        printf("%c",s[j]);
                        k=j;
                    }
                }
                printf("===");
                if(temp==1)
                {

                    printf("This Line has been commented :( \n");
                    temp=0;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("this line is  code :) \n");
                }
            }

            i++;

        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code !

**Code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

   char comment[25] ="/* this is a comment */";
   printf("%s",comment);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output :**

/* this is a comment */