# Shell remove string including newlines

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I am currently working on a custom source patcher and I'm having troubles with replacing string by another, including newlines.

For instance, I want to remove this pattern :

```
\n/* @patch[...]*/
```

In order to get this... :

```
this.is = code ;
/* @patch beta
    blah blah
*/
if (!this.is) return 0 ;
/* @patch end */
```

... to this :

```
this.is = code ;
if (!this.is) return 0 ;
```

And **not** this :

```
this.is = code ;
<- newline
if (!this.is) return 0 ;
<- newline
```

---

Using a shell script, I'm using `sed` command in order to do what I want :

```
sed -e "s|\/\* @patch.*\*\/||g" $file > $file"_2"
```

This works pretty well, but the newlines are still there.

---

This way doesn't work as `sed` can't parse newlines :

```
sed -e "s|\n\/\* @patch.*\*\/||g" $file > $file"_2"
```

Neither this method work : [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed) , nor `tr` (second answer on the same thread).

---

Would you have any solution to this ? Even heavy ones, performance is not important here.

P.S. : I am working on a web application, and in this case JavaScript files. Under Mac OS X Yosemite, but no matter what system I'm using, it seems to be a common issue for all bash users.

---

I found out another solution using Node.js for those who have troubles with their Awk version :

```
node -e "console.log(process.argv[1].replace(/[\n\r]\/\* @patch([\s\S]*?)\*\//mg, ''))" "`cat $filepath`"
```

Comment: Don't use `s///` use `/pat/d`.

Comment: `d` deletes current line. check with a nice tuto will help http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html

Comment: What if `/*` and `*/` are not on same line?

Comment: I just found a duplicate answer that seems quite good. Also, deleting my answer since I was just covering one-line comments (for posterity, it was based on @EtanReisner 's suggestion: `sed '/^\/\* @patch.*\*\/$/d' file`)

Comment: P.S. : The 'already answering' related topic does not answer my question at all. Please unmark my question as duplicated unless you find a real solution elsewhere to my issue.

Comment: @Tot it seems that you have some different tools here. Update your question explaining what is your exact system, what sed you are using, etc. Otherwise, people will keep updating their answer after any of your updated. Reopening the question, I had marked as duplicate to [Remove multi-line comments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13061785/1983854)

Comment: @fedorqui Alright, I understand your point. But this topic was neither answering the main problem as it was too specific to C. That is why I didn't understand this duplication mark.

Comment: These *are* C comments and that answer is not C specific

Comment: @fedorqui Indeed, it performs correctly with my files. :) However it removes all comments (I don't know how to put the `@patch` rule in that regex), plus it doesn't remove the newlines where the comments have been erased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, for anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{gsub(/[*][/]/,"\0"); gsub(/\n[/][*] @patch[^\0]+\0/,""); gsub(/\0/,"*/")} 1' file
this.is = code ;
if (!this.is) return 0 ;
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS to read the whole file as a single string (with other ask you just build up the string line by line and process in the END section) and relies on your file not containing any NUL (`\0`) characters.

The first `gsub()` changes every `*/` to one char (a NUL) so the 2nd `gsub()` can negate it in a bracket expression as part of your desired regexp and then the third `gsub()` restores any remaining NULs to `*/`s.

With non-gawk you need to build up the string:

```
awk '{rec = rec $0 RS} END{gsub(/[*][/]/,"\0",rec); gsub(/\n[/][*] @patch[^\0]+\0/,"",rec); gsub(/\0/,"*/",rec); printf "%s",rec}' file
```

and it sounds like your awk requires the `/`s in the bracket expressions escaped so it doesn't see them as the terminating char of the RE:

```
awk '{rec = rec $0 RS} END{gsub(/[*][\/]/,"\0",rec); gsub(/\n[\/][*] @patch[^\0]+\0/,"",rec); gsub(/\0/,"*/",rec); printf "%s",rec}' file
```

If your awk doesn't like NUL chars then use some control character, e.g. (where every `^C` is a literal control-C character):

```
awk '{rec = rec $0 RS} END{gsub(/[*][\/]/,"^C",rec); gsub(/\n[\/][*] @patch[^^C]+^C/,"",rec); gsub("^C","*/",rec); printf "%s",rec}' file
```

or use the pre-defined `SUBSEP` control char that awk uses to separate array indices (note you now need to double-up the backslashes in the REs that are concatenation of literal strings with SUBSEPs since they are now dynamic regexps instead of constant regexps, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps for details):

```
awk '{rec = rec $0 RS} END{gsub(/[*][\/]/,SUBSEP,rec); gsub("\\n[\\/][*] @patch[^"SUBSEP"]+"SUBSEP,"",rec); gsub(SUBSEP,"*/",rec); printf "%s",rec}' file
```

Comment: I have a sort of syntax error : `[...] awk: nonterminated character class [*][ source line number 1`. I suspected the space between the `ORS=` and the following. When I remove this space, I have this error : `[...] awk: bailing out at source line 1`. :(

Comment: The space you removed is necessary as I'm setting ORS to be empty. Whatever awk you are using might need the `/` in `[/]` escaped so it becomes `[\/]` but it sounds like you're not using gawk. Try `awk --version` to find out. and I'll add a non-gawk version.

Comment: Ah indeed, I had to escape them. My awk version is `awk version 20070501`. So now it runs, however it removes all `*/`, even those not beginning with `/* @patch`. :o

Comment: Are you SURE you copy/pasted the last script in my answer exactly? If that script is removing `*/`s that don't start with `/* @patch` then best I can tell that means your awk is significantly broken as it's removing text that you haven't told it to remove but we'd need to see exactly what script you are running along with the input you are running it against and the output you are getting to be able to help you debug it so edit your question to show all of that.

Comment: Done. I've updated and added my results. And yes, I'm extra-sure that I've used all your `awk` examples. Though as you said, my `awk` might be broken, but it would be better if someone else tests the same for us.

Comment: I get the same result you do with `nawk`. All other awks I tried behave as I'd expect. Despite it's full name of `new awk`, `nawk` is a actually an old, pre-POSIX awk so it will behave "odd" at times and is best avoided if possible. It's not nearly as bad as old, broken awk though (aka `oawk`) so no need to try TOO hard to avoid it. It looks like `nawk` does not like NUL chars so replace every `\0` with some control character, e.g. `control-C` or the value of `SUBSEP`. I've updated my answer to show those options.