# Why is more data printed than I expect?

Tags: regex, perl, awk, header-files

It's the next part of another problem I have just yesterday [Awk doesn't match all match all my entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134957/awk-doesnt-match-all-match-all-my-entries). 
I want to replace awk with perl and my first goal is to extract my declarations of functions in a .c and put it in a .h. So I came up with this :

```
cat dict3.c | perl -ne '/([a-z_*]+[[:space:]]+[a-z_*]+[[:space:]]*\(.*?\))/i; print $1 . ";\n"'
```

But the output is that :

```
    ;
;
;
;
;
;
;
;
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dictent_t* dictentcreate(const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
dict_t* dictcreate();
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdestroy(*dict_t d);
void dictdump(dict_t *d);
void dictdump(dict_t *d);
void dictdump(dict_t *d);
void dictdump(dict_t *d);
void dictdump(dict_t *d);
void dictdump(dict_t *d);
void dictdump(dict_t *d);
void dictdump(dict_t *d);
void dictdump(dict_t *d);
void dictdump(dict_t *d);
void dictdump(dict_t *d);
void dictdump(dict_t *d);
int dictlook(dict_t *d, const char * key);
int dictlook(dict_t *d, const char * key);
int dictlook(dict_t *d, const char * key);
int dictlook(dict_t *d, const char * key);
int dictlook(dict_t *d, const char * key);
int dictlook(dict_t *d, const char * key);
int dictlook(dict_t *d, const char * key);
int dictlook(dict_t *d, const char * key);
int dictlook(dict_t *d, const char * key);
int dictlook(dict_t *d, const char * key);
int dictlook(dict_t *d, const char * key);
int dictlook(dict_t *d, const char * key);
int dictlook(dict_t *d, const char * key);
int dictlook(dict_t *d, const char * key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
int dictget(char* s, dict_t *d, const char *key);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t* dictadd(dict_t* d, const char * key, const char * val);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t dictup(dict_t d, const char * key, const char * newval);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
dict_t* dictrm(dict_t* d, const char * key);
```

Whereas there's just one declaration for each function in the file.
I have no clue what it could be because the number of repetitions is not the same for each printed line so it can't be just one loop...

Comment: Is that the output or is that the input, or a combination of both ?

Answer (score 4):

Because you're not making the `print` command **conditional** upon matching the regex. Try this:

```
perl -ne '/([\w*]+\s+[\w*]+\s*\(.*?\))/i and print $1 . ";\n"' dict3.c
# .......................................^^^
```

For every line, you were printing the matched text from the *last successful match*.

Comment: Ok, as I am new too perl I didn't know that syntax, but now I have the Llama with me !
Thank you

Comment: @NicolasScottoDiPerto - You probably don't need to learn a lot for this. It's just a shorthand way of saying `if ( $_ =~ /.../ ) { print $1,"\n";}`