# Execute command from variable

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk

in the continuation of this, [Awk doesn't match all match all my entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33134957/awk-doesnt-match-all-match-all-my-entries/33148175?noredirect=1#comment54135231_33148175), I am now trying to write a script to execute this on different machine. In the script, I want to run /usr/xpg4/bin/awk if it exists else regular awk.
I can't do just a simple if else because my script is too complex - I wan't to do something user friendly and it has some options.
So I record the proper awk in a variable like this :

```
command='awk '"'"'match($0,/^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*\**[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*[[:space:]]*\([^)]*\)/) { print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) ";\n" }'"'";
```

after what I try to execute it

> code=$($command $file);

I get this error :

```
awk: command line:1: 'match($0,/^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*\**[[:space:]]+[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*[[:space:]]*\([^)]*\)/)
awk: command line:1: ^ bad character « ' » in expression
```

It doesn't mean anything if I take them off...

Comment: [Don't put commands in strings. Use arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Why do you put code into data? Why don't you use a function instead of a variable? Also relevant: [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 0):

Roughly, don't do it like that.

```
AWK=/usr/xpg4/bin/awk
if [ ! -x "$AWK" ]
then AWK="awk"
fi
```

Then you can use:

```
code=$("$AWK" '…your awk script…' "$file")
```

Or you can put your script into a file, `script.awk`, and use:

```
code=$("$AWK" -f script.awk "$file")
```

We can debate the merits of the double quotes around the use of `"$AWK"`; there are pros and cons.

If you need different `awk` scripts for the different sub-species of (Solaris?) `awk`, then you can create different `script.awk` files and still use the common notation with `-f script.awk` to execute the scripts.

And there's no obligation to use the name `script.awk`; it is just illustrative.  Indeed, if you create it on the fly, you should ensure it is uniquely named (e.g. by adding `$$`, the current process ID, into the name).  Beware of security issues.  I'm not sure if Solaris comes with `mktemp` command to create a temporary file securely.

Comment: Of course there was the previous test but I omitted it since I am testing the script.
I'd prefer to have just one file so no external awk script.