# How to skip multiline comments delimited with /* */

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get the Bash script to read a text file and print out all the lines in it. I've successfully accomplished that by doing:

```
while read line; do
   $echo line
done < main.txt
```

However, I want it to ignore any lines in between `/*` and `*/`. If I have a text file that looks like this:

```
hi
hru
/* 
look at my multiline comment function OoOoOoOh 
*/
good wbu
im fine
```

It will print out:

```
hi
hru
good wbu
im fine
```

Comment: are the `/*` and `*/` always on lines by themselves, or could they show up in lines intermixed with text you want to keep vs discard, eg, can something like `keep this text /* but ignore this text` and `ignore this text */ but keep this text` occur? please update the question with these additional details; also, what code have you tried to implement your filter requirements?

Comment: You could use `sed` to preprocess the file first, to strip out the comments.

Comment: @markp-fuso They could show the way i did, or intermixed, yes

Comment: you should state that in the question as well as provide an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need `while` loop, here is a one-liner:

```
$ sed -r ':a;$!{N;ba};s|/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/\n||' main.txt
hi
hru
good wbu
im fine
```

If insisting on `while`:

```
while read line; do
  echo "$line"
done < <(sed -r ':a;$!{N;ba};s|/\*[^*]*\*+([^/*][^*]*\*+)*/\n||' main.txt)
hi
hru
good wbu
im fine
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add: sed taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061785/remove-multi-line-comments

Comment: doesn't work if `/*` or `*/` show up in the middle of a line with both 'keep' and 'discard' text