# Deleting c-style block comments from multiple files

Tags: linux, sed, scripting

I have files that have a header file that I need to remove.

```
/***....*
.
.
.
***.....*/
```

It is a block like this.

I have used a sed command to remove this block.

```
sed -i '0,/^\/*\*/d' filename
```

It only removes the first line of the block comment (e.g) `/***....*`

and I wish for it to remove the whole block.

I have tried using:

`sed -i '/^.*\/\/*/d' filename`, but that removes all occurrences of `/*...*/`

Comment: `sed -i '1,/^\**\/$/d' file`?

Comment: This might help: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: I believe the GCC compiler is the best tool for the job. Also see [How can I delete all /* */ comments from a C source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1714530/608639), [Removing c-style comments with sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/503784), [Remove multi-line comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13061785/608639), [Remove comments from C/C++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2394017/608639), [Remove C and C++ comments using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/241327/608639) and friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `awk` will remove the block:

```
cat file
Beginning
/***....*
.
.
.
***.....*/
End of block
Some data

awk '/^\/\*\*/ {f=1} !f; /^\*\*/ {f=0}' file
Beginning
End of block
Some data
```

`/^\/\*\*/ {f=1}` If line starts with `/**` set flag `f` to `1`
`!f;` If flag is not set print the line
`/^\*\*/ {f=0}` if line starts with `**` clear flag `f`

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.